# Google Search Console says: "Please update your links to point to the new report"

Tags: google, google-search-console, performance, reporting

Today when I visited Search Console for my website, I seen this:

> Important: This report will soon be replaced by the new Performance Report . Please update your links to point to the new report.

[image]

To be honest, I didn't understand what does it mean. Any idea what should I do now? Is my website in danger?

Answer (score 2):

So apparently they mean links to search console itself, so like if you have a link on a blog post to search console or if you have an app that links to search console for some reason, that's what they're talking about.

I was confused too. They wrote it really cryptically, as though I needed to update some link I didn't know about on my own website that somehow links my site to search console, but apparently they just wrote the alert poorly.

Here's some more information on it by people who know more than I do. I asked the same question there and got a response from someone who knows what's up.

https://www.seroundtable.com/google-search-console-replace-search-analytics-report-26732.html

Comment: Another possibility that would need to be updated is a bookmark in your web browser to search console.